# For all/Exists in both ways

Tags: notation

Is there a more compact expression to write (without repeating the "same" sentence and using the conjunction):
$\forall a \in A \exists b\in B | d(a,b) < 100 \wedge \forall b \in B \exists a \in A | d(a, b) < 100$ ?